# Ionic 2 InAppBrowser won't load inserted links

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, inappbrowser

Searching everywhere for an answer. My app has links that are inserted dynamically inserted when loading the content from AJAX.

I want all links that the user clicks on to open in the InAppBrowser or the System Browser. However, everything is opening in the web view.

I've tried numerous things.

`gap://` is in the content policy
URLs are properly encoded
Made a `window.open = (url, target?, opts?) => this.iab.create(encodeURI(url), '_blank', 'location=yes,hidden=no');` in the `app.component.ts`

My other code works where clicking a link opens the InAppBrowser correctly, but this doesn't seem to work on regular links `<a href`

Everyone seems to have some sort of issue with InAppBrowser, what is the definitive way to do this!?

Comment: Further debugging window.open() works fine, but clicking on a link inside content doesn't trigger window.open it just navigates to the link in the web view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a work around like below

1. Please ensure InAppBrowser plugin added
2. Add code for component to handleClick event
3. On the view, I add and click event for dynamic content

```js
handleClick(event) {
      if(this.platform.is('core'))
        return;
      if (event.target.tagName == "A") { 
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
      // open link using inappbrowser
        var url = event.target.getAttribute('href');
        console.log(url);
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                    let browser = new InAppBrowser(url, '_blank');
                    browser.show();
        });
      }
    }
```

```html
   <p (click)="handleClick($event)" [innerHTML]="item.content">></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing similar but I put it into a pipe because the content is dynamic instead of an event.